# VLookup and drag and drop using vba in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My code gets `emp_id` from `hc` and puts it into another excel file dashboard in column A. My second code uses `emp_id` as a reference and then gets me the employee attributes using `VLookup`. But I can do this for a specified range only. How can I run it for the number of times col A has `emp_id` value? Or instead of manually dragging the VLookup values down I'm trying to automate it to the number of times col A has `emp_id`.

this is the code to retrieve emp_id.

```
Sub test1()
' test1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+P
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("g:\Work\Global Headcount.xlsx")

    ' Windows("Global Headcount.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.copy
    Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

   Call wbk.Close(False)
```

This code fills the values of a specific range

```
Sub RangeFill()
    Range("B4:ZZ4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B4:ZZ8"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B4:ZZ8").Select
End Sub
```

I am new at this,its been a week since i'm using vba...
any advice would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say Cell B1 contains the formula you want to AutoFill you could do something like:

```
Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2))
```

This will fill the formula in B1 to the end of data in column B.

If you have many formulas that you need to AutoFill at once you can use the same method but change the range values like this:

```
Range("B1:C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3))
```

Comment: Ripster, dude you are awesome.
Worked like a charm saved me a ton of time.
however my code highlights the emp_id column what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked for you! Will you please explain what you mean by it highlights the emp_id column? If it is selecting it you can add a Range("A1").Select to select the first cell as long as the autofill is working properly. Will you please elaborate?